# Converting Java file to Kotlin now it won't compile - "Internal compiler error"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

I'm working on converting a Java Android project to Kotlin in Android Studio and I'm getting problems.

It worked fine when I had converted one file to Kotlin with the MainActivity still being in Java but after converting the MainActivity the code no longer compiles. It fails with a Gradle / Kotlin related error and the stack trace isn't very useful and doesn't point to anything in my code.

**[MainActivity.kt source](https://paste.pound-python.org/show/3jliYACRQIz0ng8hqIqD/)**

**Any ideas please? Here's the stack trace:**

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Internal compiler error. See log for more details
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:17)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.processCompilerExitCode(Tasks.kt:441)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:403)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:297)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:259)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Full build log:** https://paste.pound-python.org/show/XgPRLyb3JLBdsCZkUFPJ/

Thanks :)

Comment: Your build log could also give some important info. Do you have any errors on the bottom of the build log?

Comment: @CodeRed I'll check again later but I'm pretty sure it just points back to this error.

Comment: It is not the complete stacktrace; the complete stacktrace provides more information and usually points to a specific place in the code which triggered the internal compiler error.

Comment: @yole I've added a link to the full log, do you see anything obvious? I still find it very unclear :(

Comment: Is it possible to share source file?

Comment: @aminography Yeah I'll add the MainActivity tonight (at work atm). I might also try creating a new AndroidStudio project and manually copying the source code to see if that fixes it.

Comment: @aminography I've added the `MainActivity.kt` sourcecode file which is causing the problem.

Comment: @yole See answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from converting the `OnClickListener`s. I've checked your code and found that the kotlin compiler can not detect its lambda form. Try to change the `OnClickListener`s as following:

```
@Suppress("ObjectLiteralToLambda")
class MainActivity : Activity() {

    // private val randomFactListener = OnClickListener {
    //    // code block
    // }

    private val randomFactListener = object : OnClickListener {

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            // code block
        }
    }

    // private val backToHomeListener = OnClickListener {
    //    // code block
    // }

    private val backToHomeListener = object : OnClickListener {

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            // code block
        }
    }

    // private val anotherRandomFactListener = OnClickListener {
    //    // code block
    // }

    private val anotherRandomFactListener = object : OnClickListener {

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            // code block
        }
    }

}
```

[Here](https://hastebin.com/ucoqaturox.cpp) is your corrected `MainActivity.kt` complete source code.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it later today and let you know :D

Comment: Okay thanks, this has sort of fixed it (with a few tweaks). I've had to comment out line 96 because it's some sort of dependency loop problem where I'm calling a listener from within another listener which is called by the listener that called it - if that makes sense? Trying to work out a way to restructure my code to allow this.

Comment: I've now fixed it by totally restructuring the code - the whole project was a mess, trying to convert a 2012 project to Kotlin which was badly structured to begin with. Thanks for your help I have a good base to start from now :) @yole I must say that sadly the Kotlin compiler errors weren't very helpful in spotting the problem in this instance.

Comment: I think converting a developed project to kotlin is not a good idea because of difference in java and kotlin grammar that makes such issues. You're welcome friend.

Comment: Yeah it's OK because the project isn't very big and I'm trying to restructure it all!